# Polymer 0.9 array push with repeat template

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using Polymer 0.9 and I have this template.

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menuPages}}">
            <li class="c-text">
                <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

When I use this snippet to update the data it doesn't load

```
    ready: function () {
        this.menuPages.push({title:'hey'});
        this.menuPages.push({title:'hey2'});
    }
```

However this works

```
    ready: function () {
        this.menuPages = [{title:'hey'}, {title:'hey2'}];
    }
```

[Working Example](http://bstavroulakis.com/demos/stackoverflow/polymer-09-loop/working.html)

[Not Working Example](http://bstavroulakis.com/demos/stackoverflow/polymer-09-loop/not-working.html)

Comment: The official documentation is really bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to trigger the DOM updates you'll have to use this:

```
this.push('menuPages', {title:'hey'});
```

Documentation: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat